# union query in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, union-all

This is my code

```
Transform IIf(IsNull(Count(monthTable.monthNumber)), 
            "0", 
            IIf(Count(monthTable.monthNumber) = 0, 
                "Yes", 
                IIf(Count(monthTable.monthNumber) < 1, 
                    "error", 
                    first(Resource_Allocation.[Chargebility]))))
SELECT Resource_Allocation.[Employee ID],
       Resource_Allocation.[Project Name],
       first(Resource_Allocation.[Project Tower]) AS Tower,
       first(Resource_Allocation.[Enterprise ID]) AS [Enterprise Id],
       first(Resource_Allocation.[Role Title]) AS [Role Title],
       first(Resource_Allocation.[Chargebility]) AS chargeblity,
       first(Resource_Allocation.[Actual Roll-On Date]) AS [Role On Date],
       first(Resource_Allocation.[Estimated Roll-Off Date]) As [Role Off Date]
FROM Resource_Allocation,
     monthTable
WHERE monthTable.monthNumber BETWEEN
    iif(Resource_Allocation.[Actual Roll-On Date] > #1-1-2016#,
        iif(Resource_Allocation.[Actual Roll-On Date] < #31-12-2016#,
            month([Resource_Allocation]![Actual Roll-On Date]),
            iif(Resource_Allocation.[Actual Roll-On Date] < #1-1-2016# ,0,1)),
        iif(Resource_Allocation.[Estimated Roll-Off Date] < #1-1-2016#,0,0))
AND iif(Resource_Allocation.[Estimated Roll-Off Date] > #1-1-2016#,
        iif(Resource_Allocation.[Estimated Roll-Off Date] < #31-12-2016#,
            month([Resource_Allocation]![Estimated Roll-Off Date]),
            iif(Resource_Allocation.[Estimated Roll-Off Date] < #31-12-2016#,0,12)),
        iif(Resource_Allocation.[Estimated Roll-Off Date] < #1-1-2016#,0,0))
GROUP BY Resource_Allocation.[Project Name],
         Resource_Allocation.[Employee ID] 
PIVOT monthTable.monthName IN(January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December);
```

I want the sum of all data in the months present in the column in the last row.  I tried it using union all but it is not working

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: First of all change format of all dates inside the query to american one: #mm/dd/yyyy# or standard: #yyyy/mm/dd# and try again

Comment: Second, string literals need to be in the `PIVOT ... IN()` clause. So wrap months in quotes.